# .50 cal bullets killing people without hitting them, via pressure wave or some other mechanism

Tags: medical-science

There is a persistent myth, even among military members, that certain types of rounds can kill a human without actually impacting.  Myths like "it can snap your neck as it passes by" or "it can tear your arm off if it passes near you".  Most examples I've heard deal with .50 caliber sniper rounds, although I've also heard the same about the A-10 Warthog's 30mm rounds.  Any validity at all?  What about artillery or other types of munitions killing by merely passing near a target on its flight path?

Comment: It goes without saying that artillery rounds of sufficient size can kill you by exploding nearby.

Comment: Yea but if you read the last line it specifically clarifies "...killing by merely passing near [a person] on its flight path".

Comment: This has become such a persistent question asked on the Mythbusters forum that we have a "sticky" section at the top of the "Weapons" thread dealing specifically with myths associated with the .50 BMG.

Although it's true that supersonic projectiles can create a very localized sonic boom (audible as a loud crack if you are close) no damage results.  Even the big .50 BMG projectile is still quite small, and simply can't move enough air to cause any damage.

Comment: I've heard a similar thing about the 5.56mm round. Allegedly, it's so fast that it has a lethal effect even if it only flies past your skin, causing some nerves to go into some kind of "fireworks" mode. I've yet to see any proof of this story, however.

Comment: A-10 30mm rounds obviously have other mechanics of kill besides direct hit, as they use mix of high-explosive incendiary (HEI) and depleted uranium armor-piercing incendiary (API), typically 1 HEI per 4 API.

Comment: Rough calculation suggests that a 1 metre length of air displaced by a 50mm round travelling at 1000 m/s (VERY fast) is given about 1500 Joule on energy. That's very significant IF you can direct it. But at 333 m/s that's down to about 170 J. Getting all the energy into an adjacent body would be "exceedingly hard". | The 1000 m/s round would certainly be noticeable.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think there's an episode of Mythbusters that disproves the .50 BMG killing by pressure waves claim. They shot several times through a narrow corridor of glass cups and not even one broke because of the alleged pressure waves from the travelling bullet.

EDIT: Here's a link for a description of this specific episode http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MythBusters_(2009_season)#Sonic_Boom_Sound-off

Comment: Cool.    How about the Vulcan cannon or arty rounds?

Comment: Never seen any experiments or real life reports covering these calibers, sorry. Personally, I think its the same as with the .50 BMG.

Comment: Whilst this may technically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Blockquotes are [an excellent way to do this](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/164/315#315).

Comment: Pining you, can you find a better reference here?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know of any other relevant references.

Comment: Maybe you can expand the answer out to cover other rounds as mentioned in the question itself?

Comment: I wish I could but I'm not aware of any such experiments made with those particular rounds.